# Is it possible to delete a property from an object by setting it to undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have code like this:

```
const o = { x: 'hello' };
o.x = undefined;
const o2 = { ...o };
// can now ('x' in o2 === false) ?
```

Can garbage collector delete key after set `undefined`

Comment: You've set the property value to be `undefined` but the property still exists. Use `delete o.x` to remove the property entirely.

Comment: I have a problem with logger that used `JSON.stringify` that removes `undefined` values XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the key `x` won't be deleted, because `undefined` is a valid value for an object property. `undefined` is [one of the javascript primitive types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive).

In order to remove the property from the object you have to use delete:

```
delete o.x
```

The string "hello" will eventually be freed by the garbage collector if there is no more references to it.

You can find a good explanation of how the garbage collector works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#garbage_collection).

Comment: They didn't ask about `"hello"`, the question was whether the `x` key can be removed from the object.

Answer (score 1):

No. Even though reading a nonexistent property returns `undefined`, it's not the same as a property that has been explicitly set to `undefined`. This is because functions like `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` return all the keys, not just the ones that have values other than `undefined`, and it would change the result. Similarly, `"x" in o` doesn't care about the value. In addition, an explicit property will shadow a property that's inherited from a prototype.

Also, the garbage collector doesn't remove references, it only collects objects that have no references. Exceptions are `WeakMap` and `WeakSet`, which are specifically designed to not count as references by the GC. But the above reason is why you can't get a list of the keys of a `WeakMap`.

Comment: You can set "x" to be non-enumerable then it won't show in Object.keys() and still exist in the object. The result of Object.keys() does not define property existence.

Comment: That was just an example, there's also `.hasOwnProperty()`.

Comment: @TiagoBértolo Then `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` does? Or `"x" in o` does? Or `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, "x")`?

Comment: . getOwnPropertyNames() will list non-enumerable properties, Object.keys() won't.

Test it yourself: `const cc = Object.create(Object.prototype,{name: {
    value: undefined,
    enumerable: false
  }})`

Comment: I already changed the answer.